# Pointwise and Uniform Boundedness on Banach Spaces

Tags: functional-analysis

I'm working on the following problem in Royden:

> As a consequence of the Baire Category Theorem we showed that a mapping that is the pointwise limit of a sequence of continuous mappings on a complete metric space must be continuous at some point. Use this to prove that the pointwise limit of a sequence of linear operators on a Banach space has a limit that is continuous at some point and hence, by
>   linearity, is continuous.

I'm stuck on how to start, linear operators on Banach Spaces need not be continuous. So I don't know how to get started. Even if I did know this, its not clear to me how linearity helps me go from pointwise continuity to full continuity.

Comment: I suspect the sequence of linear operators are each required to be continuous - if not just take the constant sequence of some discontinuous operator.

Comment: could you elaborate on your comment about a constant sequence of a discontinuous operator? do you mean a sequence of such operators or such an operator acting on a sequence?

Comment: For some discontinuous operator $T$, the sequence $(T,T,T,T,T,\dotsc)$ is what I mean.